# Печать из нескольких источников формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Каким образом, можно вывести на печать сразу из нескольких полей?
У меня на форме есть два `combobox` и один `textbox`.
Причем textbox с нестандартным шрифтом.
Сейчас я соорудил такую конструкцию из кода, но это просто набросок.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string name, surname,cnv, result;

        name = cbName.Text;
        surname = cbSurName.Text;
        cnv = tbText.Text;
        result = (name + ": " + Surname + "\n" +"\n" + cnv);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(result, new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 125);
    }
```

Как видно, я просто завел строковые переменные, в которые записал значения компонентов формы, переменную с результатом я просто добавил в строку где описываются аргументы для принтера.
Но я уверен, что это не правильно:) Хотя работает. С указанием стандартного шрифта конечно же.
А хотелось бы, что бы на печать шел набор указанных мной шрифтов.

Comment: Т.е ты хочешь напечатать за раз 3 строчки разными шрифтами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то ты хочешь напечатать 3 строки с использыованием разных шрифтов.

В таком случае ты можешь вызвать:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(*)
```

по разу для каждой печатываемой строки(3 переменных) строки. Тебе потребуется лишь менять 2 последних координаты, что бы результат записывался друг за другом.

Comment: Именно. У меня в комбобоксах обычная информация которая выводится шрифтом Times New Roman. А в текстбоксе уже свой шрифт.
На бумагу надо вывести комбобоксы с их стандартным шрифтом и текстбокс с его кастомным шрифтом.